# regular expression for getting @ and after that

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for the string filtering. I want to get the symbol "@" and anything that is written after that and before a space.

Can someone help me with this?

For example:

```
hi I am @vaibhav .
```

The expected result this regular expression should give is `vaibhav`.

I made this:

```
/@[a-z]*/
```

However, I am not sure if this will confirm to the above mentioned criteria.

Comment: Please.. at least try something minimal.

Comment: Sorry all I haven't mentioned my try.. I made this : /@[a-z]*/ but I am not sure if this will confirm to the above mentioned criteria.

Comment: @vaibhav: You need to add that to the post itself. Is it JavaScript?

Comment: Once you provide the language, we could help you with the code.

Comment: @vaibhav Your `@[a-z]*` regex will work perfectly for capturing only lowercase alphabetic characters. It will not match any other characters, and will return an empty string if the `'@'` is not followed by a lowercase alphabetic character. If that meets your needs, I'd suggest providing it as answer and accepting it.

Comment: @stribizhev yeah....I did forget to mention that ... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a substring from the `@` up to the first space after it, use

```
@\S+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY2cS1/1)

The `\S` means *a non-whitespace character*.

If you do not need `@`, use a capturing group:

```
@(\S+)
```

The value you need will be in Group 1. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY2cS1/2).

If you are using JavaScript:

```js
var re = /@(\S+)/g; 
var str = 'hi I am @vaibhav . hi, and I am @strib .';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.write("The value is: <b>" + m[1] + "</b><br/>");
}
```

Comment: thanks @stribizhev your answer worked perfectly and I added a little tweek to it by adding "/@(\S+)/g" global call for it so that it can trace any such occurrence further.

Comment: You did not mention that you have several matches in one input string. Surely, `/g` should work alright since the regex will never match an empty string and the index will get moved along.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use a negated set.

1. Search characters that are not `'@'`
2. Read in the `'@'`
3. Now capture characters that are not `' '`

If you're trying to match and capture you can accomplish that like this:

```
[^@]*@([^ ]*).*
```

[[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/uW2fF2/1)]

If you only want to search then you don't need to match the whole string and you can just extract the actual match section:

```
@([^ ]*)
```

[[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/qN2rY9/1)]

The most complicated situation is where you need to deal with an escaped `'@'`. Here's an example of a match using that:

```
(?:[^\\@]|\\.)*@([^ ]*).*
```

[[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/nM2gM7/2)]

Comment: The `[^@]*@([^ ]*).*` is for Java's `String#matches`, right? Good one, but might fail if there is a newline after `@`. `@([^ ]*)` is semantically the same as my suggestion, only the space is a literal, not accounting for other whitespace.

Comment: @stribizhev It will not "fail" in any case. If the regex is in single line mode it  will return an empty string for the capture. If the regex is in multi line mode it will capture the newline and everything up to a `' '`.

Comment: *If the regex is in single line mode* - you have not specified that mode in any of your regexps. Also, we still do not know what language is used.

Comment: @stribizhev Defaults to single line mode? So the input string: "hi I am @\n" would capture: ""

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Edited version:

```
(?<=@)\w+
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dO4tB3/2)

Comment: The only trouble is that we do not know if it is JavaScript or not. JS regex engine does not support look-behinds.

Comment: @stribizhev Even if it did support look-behinds they're expensive and should be avoided.

Comment: Especially when unanchored like here.